# How can I start the game with a random formation?

Tags: unity, c#

```
public class SquadFormation : MonoBehaviour
{
    enum Formation
    {
        Square, Circle, Triangle
    }

    [Header("Main Settings")]
    public Transform squadMemeberPrefab;
    public int columns = 4;
    [Range(4, 100)]
    public int numberOfSquadMembers = 20;
    public float yOffset = 0;
    [Range(1, 20)]
    public int numberOfSquads = 1;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Formations")]
    public int squareSpace = 10;
    public int circleSpace = 40;
    [Range(3,50)]
    public float moveSpeed = 3;
    public bool randomSpeed = false;
    [Range(3, 50)]
    public float rotateSpeed = 1;
    public float threshold = 0.1f;
    public bool destroySquad = false;
    public string currentFormation;
    public bool startRandomFormation = false;

    private Formation formation;
    private List<Quaternion> quaternions = new List<Quaternion>();
    private List<Vector3> newpositions = new List<Vector3>();
    private bool move = false;
    private bool squareFormation = false;
    private List<GameObject> squadMembers = new List<GameObject>();
    private float[] step;
    private int[] randomSpeeds;
    private int index = 0;
    private int numofobjects = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        numofobjects = numberOfSquadMembers;
        if (startRandomFormation)
        {
            formation = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3);
        }
```

In this case I have 3 formations. But it might later more or less formations.
Making this line is has no sense:

```
formation = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3);
```

The idea is to start randomly with one of the 3 formations.

How can I get the number of formations ? The count in the enum ? And how can I select randomly one formation ?

Comment: The line to get the random enum item is:  formation = (Formation)UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 3); but how can I get the number of items in the enum ? Instead 0, 3 something like 0, Formation.Count ?

Comment: ...did you try searching for "C# number of items in enum"? This is covered rather extensively elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question essentially boils down to "how do I get the number of elements in an enum in C#", which is [already answered on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571197/simplify-c-sharp-code-to-obtain-number-of-elements-in-an-enum):

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(Formation)).Length;
```

But I would recommend a different approach than an enum for this situation.

Your formations are certainly more than just an integer. A formation is actually a list of positions, and maybe even some information about how members of the formation behave at runtime. That means it might make sense to create a `class Formation` which contains all data and code specific to each formation. You can then have a `Formation[] possibleFormations` in your `SquadFormation` class.

You could even go one step further and make `SquadFormation` a [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html). That way you can create new squad formations as assets, edit them in a custom-made editor and assign them to your `SquadFormation` game objects using the inspector.